# Running each iteration in a for loop in parallel

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have the following code:

```
for i in "${atomic_mass[@]}"
do
        cd /home/eric2207/data/Z=66
        mkdir DY"$i"
        for j in "${deformation[@]}"
        do
                cd /home/eric2207/DRHBc
                make clean
                sed -e "s/\${A}/$i/" -e "s/\${beta}/$j/" $input > $output
                make
                cd /home/eric2207/data/Z=66/DY"$i"
                mkdir ./"$j"
                cd ./"$j"
                cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc/1drhbws .
                cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc/dir.dat .
                cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc/paramet.for .
        done
done
```

My question is how do I run the commands for all the j in parallel?
That is, I want the commands in each j to run sequentially but the commands for all the j to run  in parallel.
I found that one can do

```
parallel --jobs (number of commands) < (file)
```

However, this does not help me in my case as I want the commands nested in the second for loop to run sequentially.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Run them in a subshell in the background? I think something like `(command1; command2; command3) &` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not at a proper computer, but:

```
for
do
   ...
   for 
   do
      (
        ...
        ...
      ) &
   done
   wait
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do_one() {
  i="$1"
  j="$2"
  jobslot="$3"
  cd /home/eric2207/data/Z=66
  mkdir -p DY"$i"
            cd /home/eric2207/
            # You need a new dir per combination due to race condition
            rsync -a DRHBc/ DRHBc-"$jobslot"/
            cd DRHBc-"$jobslot"
            make clean
            sed -e "s/\${A}/$i/" -e "s/\${beta}/$j/" $input > $output
            make
            cd /home/eric2207/data/Z=66/DY"$i"
            mkdir ./"$j"
            cd ./"$j"
            cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc-"$jobslot"/1drhbws .
            cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc-"$jobslot"/dir.dat .
            cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc-"$jobslot"/paramet.for .
}
export -f do_one
parallel do_one {1} {2} {%} ::: "${atomic_mass[@]}" ::: "${deformation[@]}"
```

Force outer loop in serial:

```
inner() {
  i="$1"
  parallel -q do_one "$i" {1} {%} ::: "${deformation[@]}"
}
export -f inner
env_parallel --env deformation -j1 inner ,,, "${atomic_mass[@]}"
```